# An exercise in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a group generated by two elements $a$ and $b$. satisfies $a^{p^m}=1$ , $b^{p^r}=1$ and $b^{-1}ab=a^n$ where $p$ is a prime number. Prove that any two subgroups of $G$ are commute under multiplication. That is, for any two subgroups $H_1, H_2$, we have $H_1H_2=H_2H_1$.

Comment: I have no idea about it...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct.  $b^{-1}ab=a^n\iff ab=ba^n$.  Therefore, if $b$ is behind $a$, we may "interchage" them, so every element of $G$ can be expressed as $b^s a^t$.  Suppose $b^{s_i} a^{t_i} \in H_i, i=1,2$.  $b^{s_1} a^{t_1} b^{s_2} a^{t_2}$ and $b^{s_2} a^{t_2} b^{s_1} a^{t_1}$ give different results.

Comment: We needn't to prove this group is commutative. since $H_1H_2=H_2H_1$ means for any pair of $h_1 \in H_1, h_2 \in H_2$, we can find $g_1 \in H_1, g_2 \in H_2$ satisfies $h_1h_2=g_2g_1$.

Comment: This is not true - take $p=m=2$, $r=1$, and $n=3$. Then you get the dihedral group $D_4$ of order $8$ and it is easy to find two subgroups of order $2$ that do not commute.

Comment: Perhaps it is true when $p$ is an odd prime?

Comment: As pointed out by @GNUSupporter, you should be careful with your $n$. Your group is definitely finite, and $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup. Conjugation by $b$ should induce an automorphism on $\langle a \rangle$, so you need $p \nmid n$.

Comment: Dear @MinghuiOuyang : avoid using titles that apply equally well to every group theory problem that exists. Be more specific. I will not even bother to read your question for this reason, and I'm probably not alone.

Comment: @rschwich Thank you for reminding. I will do it next time.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti yes, $p,m,r,n$ have some restriction, we can just assume that this kind of group exist.

Comment: @NickyHekster Maybe $p$ need to be a odd prime number.